# Why Firestore "projects.databases.documents.list" also includes document fields?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore there is a principle of creating small documents and big collections. However this doesn't make seanse if we use Firestore using it's REST API, because listing collection also prints content of all documents within it. This doesn't make sense to me at all, shouldn't it be supposed to just return id's of all documents? Here is the exact method I'm talking about: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list

Comment: If one of the functions in your app is to get all documentId's and none of the child data then you should create a collection of just documentId's that contains a key: value pair of `documentId: true'. That's a very common practice (duplication, denormalization) in NoSQL databases. See this somewhat vintage but still relevant article [Denormalizing is Norma](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)

Answer (score 0):

The API is working correctly.  If you don't want any document fields (or limited fields), you can use the mask parameter as described in API docs you linked:

> object(DocumentMask)
>
> The fields to return. If not set, returns all fields.
>
> If a document has a field that is not present in this mask, that field
>   will not be returned in the response.

Comment: I haven't said that the api is working uncorrectly, but rather I don't understand why it has been designed this way. Why list jusn't just give you document's ids, when the whole purpose of collection system is to not need to read everything, but only document's that you need?

Comment: Because the cost of consulting the index to get the IDs is essentially the same as the cost of reading each entire document.  I suspect that the creators of the API thought it didn't really make sense to "optimize" this call by leaving out the contents of the document, except for the purpose of saving bandwidth.  That's when the `mask` parameter becomes useful.

Comment: If you don't like the way the API works, or you need to raise an issue with engineering staff about the specifics of this API, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @PawełKiełb I think it may be an assumption that the *whole purpose of collection system is to not need to read everything*. [a collection is a grouping of some variable number of data items (possibly zero) that have some shared significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(abstract_data_type)). However, *just getting documentId's* doesn't go with the rest of the statement *but only document's that you need* as you can easily get just the documents you need via a query.